# Как получить длину строки на scala

Tags: scala

Как получить длину строки на Scala? Есть какая нибудь функция для этого?

Comment: Ну, так же как и в Java — `.length()` ?

Answer (score 5):

```
var str = "Foobar";
var len = str.length();
```